# Proving that $t_n = r_n$

Tags: generating-functions, integer-partitions

Given a non-negative integer $n,$ let $t_n$ be the number of ways to partition $n$ using only powers of $2$ where each power is used at most three times, and let $r_n$ be the number of ways to partition $n$ using $1,2,3,9$ where $1$ and $3$ are used at most twice. Prove that $t_n = r_n.$

---

For $t_n,$ I let $n = \sum_i c_i2^i$ such that $0 \leq c_i \leq 3$ and then applied generating functions to give me $t_n = \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor + 1.$ However, I don't quite know how to calculate $r_n.$

Comment: Wanted to add that the somewhat strange conditions for the partitions counted by $r_n$ come from the way $1-q^9$ factors: since $1/(1-q) = (1+q+q^2)(1+q^3+q^6)/(1-q^9)$, allowing any number of 1s gives the same count as allowing any number of 9s, up to two 1s, and up to two 3s.  (Allowing any number of 2s just makes the problem more involved.)  The identity $1-q^{15} = (1-q)(1+q+q^2+q^3+q^4)(1+q^5+q^{10})$, for example, means that allowing any number of 1s gives the same count as any number of 15s, up to four 1s, and up to two 5s.  You can also think of this as problems about making change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $1$ and $3$ alone and at most twice each, we can write each of $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8$ and in a unique way.

Hence $r_n$ is obtained by taking any suitable number $n_2$ of $2$'s, which allows $n_2=0,1,2,\ldots, \lfloor\frac n2\rfloor$ (so $\lfloor \frac n2\rfloor +1$ ways); then use $1$'s and $3$'s as above to get down to the nearest multiple of $9$; and finally use an according amount of $9$'s. We conclude
$$r_n=\left\lfloor \frac n2\right\rfloor +1.$$

Answer (score 2):

The generating function for $t_n$ is
\begin{align}
&\quad\prod_{k \ge 0} (z^{0\cdot2^k}+z^{1\cdot2^k}+z^{2\cdot2^k}+z^{3\cdot2^k}) \\
&=\prod_{k \ge 0} (1+z^{2^k})(1+z^{2^{k+1}}) \\
&=\prod_{k \ge 0} (1+z^{2^k}) \prod_{k \ge 0} (1+(z^2)^{2^k}) \\
&=\frac{1}{1-z}\cdot \frac{1}{1-z^2} \quad \text{by uniqueness of binary expansion} \\
&=\frac{1}{(1+z)(1-z)^2}.
\end{align}

The generating function for $r_n$ is
\begin{align}
&\quad(z^{0\cdot1}+z^{1\cdot1}+z^{2\cdot1})
(z^{0\cdot2}+z^{1\cdot2}+z^{2\cdot2}+z^{3\cdot2}+\cdots)
(z^{0\cdot3}+z^{1\cdot3}+z^{2\cdot3})
(z^{0\cdot9}+z^{1\cdot9}+z^{2\cdot9}+z^{3\cdot9}+\cdots) \\
&=
(1+z+z^2)
\left(\frac{1}{1-z^2}\right)
(1+z^3+z^6)
\left(\frac{1}{1-z^9}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{(1+z)(1-z)^2}.
\end{align}

Hence $t_n=r_n$ for all $n \ge 0$.

Comment: Our answers are essentially the same; I was preparing mine when you submitted yours.  Mine has a little more exposition, but your argument for $t_n$ is cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Let me add (another) generating function solution to this problem.  As it works out, these match the number of partitions $a(n)$ with parts from $\{1,2\}$ (which, by conjugation, is the number of partitions with up to 2 parts).  The generating function for $a(n)$ is
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty a(n)q^n = \frac{1}{(1-q)(1-q^2)}.$$

The connection to $r(n)$ is pretty direct.  Its generating function is
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty r(n)q^n = \frac{(1+q+q^2)(1+q^3+q^6)}{(1-q^2)(1-q^9)}.$$
Your favorite computer algebra system can tell you that $1-q^9$ factors as $(1-q)(1+q+q^2)(1+q^3+q^6)$ so that
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty r(n)q^n = \frac{(1+q+q^2)(1+q^3+q^6)}{(1-q^2)(1-q)(1+q+q^2)(1+q^3+q^6)} = \frac{1}{(1-q)(1-q^2)} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a(n)q^n.$$

The connection to $t(n)$ is a little trickier.  Its generating function is
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty t(n)q^n = \prod_{i=0}^\infty \left(1 + q^{2^i} + q^{2\cdot 2^i} + q^{3\cdot 2^i}\right).$$
Now $\left(1 + q^{2^i} + q^{2\cdot 2^i} + q^{3\cdot 2^i}\right) = \left(1+q^{2^i}\right)\left(1+q^{2\cdot 2^i}\right)$ so that
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty t(n)q^n = \prod_{i=0}^\infty \left(1 + q^{2^i}\right)\left(1 + q^{2^{i+1}}\right)$$
where each power of 2 starting at 2 arises twice, therefore
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty t(n)q^n = (1+q)\prod_{i=1}^\infty \left(1 + q^{2^i}\right)^2.$$
Now multiply top & bottom by $(1-q)$ to get the telescoping product
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty t(n)q^n & = \frac{(1-q)(1+q)(1 + q^2)^2(1 + q^4)^2(1 + q^8)^2\cdots}{(1-q)} \\ 
& = \frac{(1-q^2)(1 + q^2)^2(1 + q^4)^2(1 + q^8)^2\cdots}{(1-q)} \\ 
& = \frac{(1+q^2)(1 - q^4)(1 + q^4)^2(1 + q^8)^2\cdots}{(1-q)} \\
& = \frac{(1+q^2)(1 + q^4)(1 - q^8)(1 + q^8)^2\cdots}{(1-q)} \\
& = \frac{(1+q^2)(1 + q^4)(1 + q^8)\cdots}{(1-q)}.
\end{align*}
Multiplying top & bottom by $(1-q^2)$ completes the collapse:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty t(n)q^n & = \frac{(1-q^2)(1+q^2)(1 + q^4)(1 + q^8)\cdots}{(1-q)(1-q^2)} \\
& = \frac{(1-q^4)(1 + q^4)(1 + q^8)\cdots}{(1-q)(1-q^2)} \\
& = \frac{(1-q^8)(1 + q^8)\cdots}{(1-q)(1-q^2)} \\
& = \frac{1}{(1-q)(1-q^2)} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a(n)q^n.
\end{align*}